# powershell.exe is terminated with exit code 1073807364

Tags: powershell, try-catch

How can I get more information why the powershell.exe exits with 1073807364?

The powershell script has inside a content like this:

```
start-transcript
try{
    # import modules xxx
    # import modules yyy
    # running function of module xxx
    # running function of module yyy
}catch{
    write-host "Errors - Global.exceptions: $global:error.exception; Script.exceptions: $script:error.exception"
    write-host "Errors - Global.exceptions: $global:error.exception; Script.exceptions: $script:error.exception"
    $_ | Out-String
}finally{
    Stop-Transcript
}
```

Comment: It's a generic exit code `DBG_TERMINATE_PROCESS` that tells nothing of the cause, so show more code, or try debugging line by line.

Comment: There are many, many lines and functions. So regarding loging I see where the logs ends so have added the try/catch also into modules-functions which are close, but still not able to get the error.

So my question is more/more general how to catch the more closer error code from module-function or script.

Comment: ... one important note, the error is not reproducable therefore cant debug line by line

Comment: So you have code which is so big you don't want to work through it, you wrap the entire code in a generic "catch" and can't see where it fails, the error is not reproducible, and your question is "recommend me some general tools/guides for troubleshooting?" - voted to close as too broad/impossible to answer/request for tutorial.

Comment: all functions in the modules which are near the error time are in separate try-catch block....simmilar to the one I described, but even so no error in transcript log....so I guess some advice like do separate transcript log for each function because the general one will never contain the error -- am I right or not?

Comment: You can have one transcript log per session unless you'd planned to stop / start it for each function (and ensure nothing overlaps). Making all logging dependent on transcript logging is a serious limitation, it is only supported in the console host and ISE. Trap may be used to catch and act on exceptions in a broader scope. However, you need a reproducible test to make that useful.

Comment: It happens on 1% to 5% of PCs. If I run the code on the PC with error it doesnot occure again. Because of that I am asking here. I would like to put as much error catching mechanizm as possible (transcript log, try-catch, ....???....) while I can't reproduce the error repeatedly. So I don't care and why not to have for example two doubled mechanizm for catching only one error. My goal is just to have more info then just what I have now the exit code 1073807364.

Comment: Maybe those PCs were doing something unusual at the time like shutting down etc?

Comment: Yes could be, but restart is not the case event log is always checked by me for shutdown events, also powershell events log is empty negative for any error. Just need some help how to insert trap or catch blocks to catch to explain the error. The transcript log is never closed so the try catch in the main script is good for nothing.... I can maybe move the stop-transcript into each catch block in module-function... It make sense to me.